# Telegraf Processor value to fieldname

Tags: time-series, influxdb, telegraf

I have points from my Input like these two:

```
http,Location=Foo Key="Humidity",Value=68 1659704523000000000
http,Location=Foo Key="Temperature",Value=24,1 1659704523000000000
```

But I have to store them like these:

```
http,Location=Foo Humidity=68 1659704523000000000
http,Location=Foo Temperature=24,1 1659704523000000000
```

I saw almost all of [Processor](https://docs.influxdata.com/telegraf/v1.14/plugins/plugin-list/) plugin docs, but I still not sure it is possible to use field value as a field name. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I still not sure it is possible to use field value as a field name. Isn't it?

Yep! The [starlark processor](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/processors/starlark) will do this. The ['pivot' example](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/master/plugins/processors/starlark/testdata/pivot.star) is what you are after.

The following will create a new field based on the values of `Key` and `Value` and then remove the original values:

```ini
[[processors.starlark]]
  source = '''
def apply(metric):
  metric.fields[str(metric.fields['Key'])] = metric.fields['Value']
  metric.fields.pop('Key',None)
  metric.fields.pop('Value',None)
  return metric
'''
```

Comment: Great! Scripting Language is really what you need in data processing. Thx!

For all: note indents!!

Comment: yeah! re: indents, [starlark](https://github.com/bazelbuild/starlark) is a dialect of Python, so spacing matters.